# Java: Timer and thread it creates

Tags: java, timer, concurrency, executorservice, executor

I have this question:

I have a timer. With scheduleAtFixedRate it creates a new Timer task. In that timer task there is certain code, which may take a while to complete. How can I make sure that Timer won't create new task when the previous one didn't complete yet?

Thanks

Answer (score 19, accepted):

My answer would be to not to use `Timer`, it's obsolete. Since Java5, `Timer` has been superseded by the `ScheduledExecutorService`, which is much more flexible and easier to use. You get finer control over how the scheduler works, the sort of control you don't get with `Timer`.

You create one using the [Executors](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html) factory class, which has a number of factory methods. The one you should be looking at is [newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor%28%29), which should do exactly what you're looking for:

> Creates a single-threaded executor
>   that can schedule commands to run
>   after a given delay, or to execute
>   periodically.  Tasks are guaranteed to
>   execute sequentially, and no more than
>   one task will be active at any given
>   time.

With a `ScheduledExecutorService`, instead of subclassing `TimerTask`, you subclass `Runnable` directly, and then submit the task to the executor. There are various methods on the executor, you need to pick which one is suitable for your needs (read the javadoc for `ScheduledExecutorService` carefully), but the gist is something like this:

```
    // initialise the executor
    ScheduledExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();

    while (tasksRemaining) {
        // create your task
        Runnable task = ....;
        // submit it to the executor, using one of the various scheduleXYZ methods
        executor.schedule(task, delay, unit);
    }

    // when everything is finished, shutdown the executor
    executor.shutdown();
```

As always, read the javadoc.

Comment: If it's obsolete and been replaced, shouldn't it be marked as @deprecated ?

Comment: In my opinion, yes, it should, but Sun's rules on deprecation are a bit mystifying. Functionally, `Timer`/`TimerTask` offers nothing over the executor framework.

Comment: Could you please show a little example of using  newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor? I am new to java, and I never heard about executors class. Thanks

Comment: Hey, I've implemented this, but I have ran another issue with it - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1937942/java-singlethreadscheduledexecutor-java-util-concurrent-rejectedexecutionexcep

Answer (score 5):

The doc for the [Timer class](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html)

> Corresponding to each Timer object is
>   a single background thread that is
>   used to execute all of the timer's
>   tasks, sequentially. Timer tasks
>   should complete quickly. If a timer
>   task takes excessive time to complete,
>   it "hogs" the timer's task execution
>   thread. This can, in turn, delay the
>   execution of subsequent tasks, which
>   may "bunch up" and execute in rapid
>   succession when (and if) the offending
>   task finally completes.

suggests that there's only *one* background thread. So I believe this scenario won't occur.

Comment: No, it will still Create the additional tasks when the old one hasn't completed yet, they simply won't execute until the first one finishes (and they may all execute immediately afterward, which is not likely the desired behavior).